# XAMPP Default Virtual Host

Tags: apache, xampp, virtualhost

I have a VPS and I have installed XAMPP in it, with all security configured. I have enabled vhosts. I have a `db.example.com` which will open `phpMyAdmin` directly on web.

The entry in `httpd-vhosts.conf` as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin"
    ServerName db.example.com
    ServerAlias www.db.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/db.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/db.example.com-access_log" common
        <Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Let's assume `1.2.3.4` is my IP for example.com. For accessing db.example.com (1.2.3.4), I will add the entry in my local `/etc/hosts` file.

I also have other entries in my `httpd-vhsots.conf` for other subdomains, which are working perfectly. To be noted, the `vhosts` entry for `db.example.com` is **first** in the file `httpd-vhsost.conf`

**Now this is the issue:**

When I open the IP `1.2.3.4` directly in my browser, `phpMyAdmin` opens, which should not happen actually. How to avoid this? I have no clue why this happens.

PS: I removed my local entry for db.example.com in `/etc/hosts`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the order of the `vhsots` entry will fix the problem. First one will act as default entry, if you hit the server via IP address directly.

So place the `vhost` in first which you want to show up while hitting IP in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can change:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

to:

```
<VirtualHost db.example.com:80>
```

When server name is specified here insdeat of "*" this vhost configuration will not catch IP address or any other name but this.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24485242)

Comment: @VihariPiratla It is not the link to the solution. This is one line of Apache configuration file. db.example.com is just exemplary server name.

Comment: Sorry, I may have marked it wrong. But please consider expanding your answer. What does it address, what's the point of checking? etc.